# armhf PWM question: what is the difference between "epwmss" and "ehrpwm"

Tags: linux, arm, beagleboneblack

I know the `epwmss` and `ehrpwm` are somehow related to PWM signals, but what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhanced High Resolution PWM (ehrpwm) is one part of the Enhanced PWM SubSystem (epwmss)

The Enhanced High-Resolution PWM features:

- Dedicated 16-Bit Time-Base Counter With
  Time and Frequency Controls
- Configurable as Six Single-Ended, Six Dual-
  Edge Symmetric, or Three Dual-Edge
  Asymmetric Outputs

All that and more is available in the [*AM335x and AMIC110 Sitara™ Processors
Technical Reference Manual*](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73o/spruh73o.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

eHRPWM is part of PWMSS.

eHRPWM is a PWM peripheral, able to generate complex pulse width waveforms with minimal CPU overhead or intervention.